# How to open a PDF file from terminal?

Tags: command-line, pdf

I used to work on the Mac terminal before and I used:

```
open file2open.pdf
```

and the PDF file would be opened on preview or whatever my default viewer was. When I use it in the terminal in Ubuntu I get this error message:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Comment: Ubuntu is not Mac (just pointing that out).

Comment: @Roland but mac claims to be a unix based system, so I assumed the terminal would behave the same atleast

Comment: Linux is not Unix.

Comment: _Linux is what Unix wanted to be, when it was growing up._

Comment: You can use fbi (Linux frame buffer image viewer) apt-get -y install fbi fbgs arch.pdf `man fbgs` for color and resolutions.

Comment: I was looking for how to open pdf in Mac and "open" is bloody perfect !

Comment: @yayu That's true for basic commands, but sometimes BASH on OS X behaves differently than on Linux

Comment: `open` works on Pop!

Answer (score 285, accepted):

#### Most desktop environments on modern systems (generic)

```
open file2open.xxx
```

OR

```
xdg-open file2open.xxx
```

#### GNOME

- until Xenial (16.04):

  ```
  gvfs-open file2open.xxx
  ```
- starting with Artful (17.10):

  ```
  gio open file2open.xxx
  ```

(`xxx` = some file extension). With this command the default app for `xxx` will be invoked (for example evince if you want to open PDF).

#### Application-specific

- Using Evince, GNOME’s default document viewer:

  ```
  evince file2open.pdf
  ```
- Using Okular, KDE’s default document viwer:

  ```
  okular file2open.pdf
  ```

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to view the text of a pdf file inside the terminal? With the pictures removed or converted to ASCII art?

Comment: That is another question. You can view with less. Example: less my-file.pdf

Comment: when using `evince` your document closes after you close the terminal. xdg-open per the elmicha's answer worked wll for me.

Comment: For gnome (3) this needs `libgnome2-bin` which is not installed by default.

Comment: `evince file2open.pdf` is simple way for the same.

Comment: I use okular just because it allows me to highlight, but it's pretty heavy. If mupdf had a highlighting feature I would not use anything else, mupdf is so fast and the keybindings are great.

Comment: `open` works on Pop!

Comment: I just realized it works on Debian stable too.

Answer (score 105):

You can also use:

```
xdg-open foo.pdf
```

xdg-open works in Gnome, KDE, xfce, LXDE and perhaps on other desktops.

You can put an alias in your ~/.bash_aliases:

```
alias open=xdg-open
```

Comment: +1. This is what chrome for one uses. It supports URIS as well (e.g. xdg-open irc://...). Pretty cool.

Comment: this is the proper answer not the one above, and this will work with all modern DEs.

Answer (score 22):

***For all those lost Mac users in Ubuntu-land ..***

Edit your **.bashrc** file, and add:

```
alias open='gnome-open'
```

Then you can just use:

```
open file2open.pdf
```

Comment: Does not work on Linux Mint with Cinnamon. `xdg-open' is the way to go.

Comment: on mint either xdb-open file.pdf or xreader file.pdf

Answer (score 15):

if the pdf is simple...

```
pdftotext -layout file2open.pdf - | more
```

We can use this in text mode, ssh, etc.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to view PDF within Terminal (Command Line Interface), try to use `zathura`.

Install Zathura `sudo apt-get install zathura -y`.

To view a PDF file just run => `zathura /path/to/xxx.pdf`

BTW: zathura requires X11 anyway, it doesn't work on Servers with no X installed.

Comment: Works great and still nicely updated on github.

Comment: `zathura` doesn't display in the current terminal (Gnome), but opens its own window?  A [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK) application?

Answer (score 11):

if you have Document Viewer installed type the following command:

```
evince Name_of_pdf_file
```

if it is not already installed you can install it firstly using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install evince
```

Comment: You could add on how to install it when it isn't

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
ooffice filename.pdf
```

to open your file in open office.

Answer (score 3):

The [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`) has suffix based alias (`-s`), these allow you to set up a file association between a file extension like `.jpg` and a suitable application like `xreader`:

```
alias -s pdf='xreader'
```

With an alias like that you just need to type the file name and hit <kbd>↵ Return</kbd>, e.g.:

```
file.pdf
```

Comment: The zsh shell has suffix based alias (-s) these allow you to set up a file association between a file extension e.g.  jpg and a suitable application say xnview

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 17.04 you case use this:

`gio open <file.pdf>`

Comment: the command `gio` is not available in Ubuntu, at least on 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a shell script:

```
$ cat pdf
#! /bin/bash

gnome-open ${1:-*.pdf}
```

When you call `pdf` it will open all pdfs in the current directory, specify which pdf by supplying an argument. I have many directories containing but one pdf file (e.g. so many LaTeX directories) so only having to write `pdf` saves me quite some time and keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following function in your `~/.bashrc`

```bsh
open () {
     read -p "Enter File Name: " ; xdg-open "$REPLY"
}
```

Comment: open () {
read -p "Enter File /location/Name: " ; ''xdg-open $REPLY''
 
}

Answer (score 0):

Too open with Libre office use:

```
loffice <file.pdf>
```

or

```
soffice <file.pdf>
```

or

Goplay -

```
gooffice <file.pdf>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also type:

```
firefox file_name.pdf
```

This will open your pdf in firefox browser.