# How to open files from folders using terminal command

Tags: command-line

I am beginning to learn and love ubuntu.  Is there any way to open files like .pdf, .jpeg, .odt, .docx etc. using command line?

For instance, I have a pdf named: `9949107741MathFormulas.pdf` in the following directory:

```
jitendra@jitendra:~/Downloads/Math.Formulas.and.Tables.8.Retail$
```

when I go to above directory type `9949107741MathFormulas.pdf` to open it, I get the message:

```
9949107741MathFormulas.pdf: command not found
```

Please advise, how can this task be accomplished?

Comment: Would you do the same thing in any other OS? Just type in a filename and hit enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fist need to ask the application to open it. For pdf, you can call "evince".

Example command:

```
evince example.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.  Do I need to close this question, if so, how can it be done?

Comment: don't have to do anything... This is a possible duplicate of [How to open a PDF file from terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43264/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-from). You did your part.

Answer (score 8):

I know you already accepted an answer but I think it will be better if you know that this has been discussed in the past with better answers like **[this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/170706/9598)**, which I reproduce right here for you.

```
xdg-open file.dvi
```

`xdg-open` will open any file with its default application. As a bonus, you can close the terminal without killing the application.

Since xdg-open is quite a long name, I put an alias for it in `.bashrc`:

```
alias go='xdg-open'
```

This way you don't need to know what application open this file or another. xdg-open will invoke whatever software is related to the file contents or extension.

Don't forget to give credit to Mihai Capotă for [his good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170706/9598).

Good luck!